# Проблема с отображением видео в редакторе TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, редактор

Я у себя на сайте подключаю редактор TinyMCE версии `4.6.4`. У него в плагинах есть плагин `media`. с помощью которого можно вставить в редактор медиа файлы.

Я в редактор добавляю видео, видео можно добавить разными способами, один из которых дать редактору прямой линк, и я так и делаю.

И в инициализации редактора есть такой параметр `media_live_embeds` который можно вставить в положение `true` или `false`, и если параметр вставить в `true` то добавленный видео можно воспроизвести прямо в редакторе.

Проблема в том что если я даю линк к видео из моего сайта (пример `vvv.mp4`) то оно не воспроизводиться (как будто параметр вставлен так `media_live_embeds: false`)․

Но если я к примеру добавляю видео линк с `youtube` (пример `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6_yRWPd4Yc`) то оно работает.

Вот на скрине есть 2 видео, первый с линком `youtube`, А второй с линком из сайта, первый воспроизводиться прямо с редактора, а второй нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем моя ошибка? у кого то была такая проблема?

Вот сам [редактор](https://jsfiddle.net/razmikgalstyan/e7x308cf/), можете пробивать сами:

Comment: путь абсолютный вставляете ?

Comment: Путь к файлу разными способами вставляю, так что файл точно виден так, такой путь если я вставлю в `video` тег `html` то оно видно, давайте посмотрим так, линк к видео пусть и с моего сайта вставляется так `http://mysite.com/vvv.mp4`, и если открыть в браузере просто это видео с линком то оно конечно нормально воспроизводиться. Оно существует по тому линку.

Comment: попробуйте добавить параметр media_filter_html:false,

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick не помогло, это вы то же можете проверить, я в низу вопроса дал ссылку на пример редактора.

Comment: Протоколы случайно не разные, типа в админку зашел по https, а видео вставляется по http ссылке?

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko нет видео то же на моем сервере например `test.mp4`. и оно должно проигрываться и в самом редакторе как в его документации написано.

Comment: Но все-таки на всякий случай - не разнятся протоколы, по которым добавляется видео и открыта админка?

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko точно нет, просто можете поставить скрипт на голый `html` файл и в том же каталоге скинуть файл видео, и так добавить в редактор, все ровно суть не меняеться

Comment: Вот что видно при попытке запустить ваш пример: This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud. Get a free API key to disable this message.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko но это не ответ на вопрос, вы док. смотрите там и без этого все должно работать, если так то зачем ссылка из ՝youtube՝ работает а та нет?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan приведите конкретный линк с вашего сайта, без него сложно что-то посоветовать.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan пока навскидку могу сказать, что это либо встроенные ограничения на загрузку видео с определенных доменов (судя по надписи "This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud"), либо дело в некорректном формате кодирования или неверных настройках сервера.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov в вопросе есть ссылка на `JSFiddle` и там все это можете тестировать, я проверил на нескольких серверах, дело не в этом, но когда там файл с определенным расширением а не ссылка на видео, то не отображается, можете откуда угодно файл скинуть и аналогично линк для видео, с линком работает а с определенным файлом нет, но в доке написано что должно работать.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Так, то есть вы загружаете файл в TinyMCE, а не ссылку? Тогда уже вопрос в настройках самого TinyMCE. Куда именно сохраняются файлы? Вполне возможно, что они не сохраняются из-за неправильных настроек редактора или передачи файлов в Cloud.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov файл с прямой ссылкой, и настройки сделаны так как в доке написано.